# CMake Error when building NAO packages

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I need to interface NAO with ROS, and I followed the instructions on http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Installation and http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Installation/remote. The only difference is that I have the 1.14.5 C++ SDK version of Naoqi, so I didn't install Python bindings. Then, I download the three packages nao_robot, naoqi_bridge and nao_extras, but when I build them I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package): 
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "naoqi_bridge_msgs" with any of the following names:

naoqi_bridge_msgsConfig.cmake
naoqi_bridge_msgs-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "naoqi_bridge_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "naoqi_bridge_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "naoqi_bridge_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
    nao_extras/nao_teleop/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222634/cmake-error-when-building-nao-packages/) by [marcofe](https://answers.ros.org/users/25343/marcofe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing the `naoqi_bridge_msgs` package.
You have to install it.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcofe](https://answers.ros.org/users/25343/marcofe/) on 2016-01-24**:
Yes, that was the issue. It really was a dummy question, sorry.
Thanks a lot :)